# Can't find my programs on the Watch Next row on Android TV Home

Tags: android-tv

I am trying to add video programs from my app to the Watch Next row on the Android TV Home.  Here's my code snippet:

```
content.put(WatchNextPrograms.COLUMN_WATCH_NEXT_TYPE, WatchNextPrograms.WATCH_NEXT_TYPE_CONTINUE);
content.put(PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_INTERNAL_PROVIDER_ID, programId);
content.put(PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_INTENT_URI, IntentUri);
content.put(Programs.COLUMN_TITLE, title);
content.put(Programs.COLUMN_SHORT_DESCRIPTION, description);
content.put(WatchNextPrograms.COLUMN_LAST_ENGAGEMENT_TIME_UTC_MILLIS, timeMilli);
content.put(PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_LAST_PLAYBACK_POSITION_MILLIS, progress);
content.put(PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_DURATION_MILLIS, duration);

Uri watchNextProgramUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Programs.CONTENT_URI, content);
```

I did get a returned uri from the insert call, but I don't see this program showing up on the android tv home (I don't even see a Watch Next row).  Am I missing something in my code or in the Android TV setup?

below is what my android tv home screen looks like and the Play Next Setting:

[image]
[image]